# problem understanding svn

Tags: svn, tabs, branch

ok at first, sry for my bad english...i hope you understand everything

i want to use svn in my company for our software developement, 
currently we use cvs but it doesn't work very well and i heard 
much good things about svn...

so anyway i have a problem understanding how i should use svn with our system...
we normally have 2 or 3 major versions in developement, lets say for 
example V1.0, V2.0 and V3.0
changes in V1.0 are merged to V2.0 and to V3.0 and so on...

beside that we have hotfixes in developement for the versions....
so our current merging goes like this:
V1.0 -> V1.1 -> V1.2 -> V2.0 -> V2.1 -> V3.0

currently every Version is an independent branch in CVS....

its always possible that we need one more hotfix for the major versions...
like lets say V1.3 (will be between 1.2 and 2.0)
this new "branch"(1.3) will be created after 2.0 and 3.0 already exists!

the merging needs to stay the same in svn
(V1.0 -> V1.1 -> V1.2 -> V2.0 -> V.2.1 -> V3.0)

so if i make a change in 1.0 it has to be in every following version...
also V2.0 is created before lets say V1.2 existed 
but when i create V1.2 the changes also need to be in V2.0...

i searched through many tutorials but there is always only one active 
developement version in every example...but we have more than one active Version...

so...how can i use our system in svn?

thank you for your help

Comment: It's not Subversion, but there's a great article that describes [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). If you're doing a lot of branching and merging, you may want to also consider Git.

Comment: Your English is pretty good. Besides, what you are trying to achieve is not simple and you may not be able to accomplish this directly using subversion (or any other tool) ,out of the box. you might have to apply your patches to all subsequent versions. Check out git. Its better at these operations than subversion.

Comment: @Greg welcome to Git Marketing Committee.

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching to a new version control system (aka VCS), i invite you to use Git instead of SVN, Git is also a VCS but is more recent. It has one main advantage which is that Git is decentralized, it means that you can work with your local repository while you are offline. It is a huge advantage, it means that you can commit modification without being able to contact a server. Some other advantages of Git is that it's fast and something that you are going to like : **it's super easy to uses branches.** You can easily merge modifications from a branch to an other.

How to start discovering Git? There are a bunch of ressources on the Internet, Git is really hype since few months (years?). You can start with that link: http://git-scm.com/ and you can also check this presentation that i find really efficient to get every concepts: http://www.slideshare.net/chacon/git-101-presentation.

Good luck!

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would use the term VCS (Version Control System), instead of CVS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just stick with the same model you had in CVS if you want multiple "active" versions, and setup your SVN repo with a new branch "/root/branches/v1.1", etc for each active version and make sure that you merge early and often to avoid overwhelming amounts of conflicts. Git apparently has a better merge algorithm, but merge conflicts can arise regardless of the VCS chosen if not managed correctly.